# Why is x undefined in the output

Tags: javascript

```js
try {
  throw new Error();
} catch (x) {
  var x = 100,
    y = 10;
  console.log(x);
  console.log(y);
}
console.log(x);
console.log(y);
```

The above code gives the output

```
100
10
undefined
10
```

Can anyone please help me understand why the value of `x` is `undefined` outside try-catch, but `y` is 10.

If I change the catch variable from x to some other random name the output comes as expected. i.e:

```js
try {
  throw new Error();
} catch (x) {
  var foo = 100,
    y = 10;
  console.log(foo);
  console.log(y);
}
console.log(foo);
console.log(y);
```

```
100
10
100
10
```

Comment: ^ If you scroll far down enough, you'll get to the whole deal on catch parameters.